# Convert and round column of string times in h:m format to time

Tags: r, time

I have a column of "times" in string format in hour and minute (no seconds)

```
time         ...
<char>
18:40        
12:20
23:59
2:15
...
```

Is there a way to convert these into times and then round them down such that my data will look like this

```
time         ...
<time>
18:00        
12:00
23:00
2:00
...
```

Comment: Do you want the final output of class `time` or `POSIXct` to you are ok with `character` class?

Comment: Thank you for responding! Could I see all 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`POSIXct` class needs both date and time, so if date is not provided it by default takes today's date. You can then use `floor_date` to round it down at the nearest hour.

```
library(lubridate)
floor_date(as.POSIXct(df$time, 'UTC', format = '%H:%M'), 'hour')

#[1] "2020-07-06 18:00:00 UTC" "2020-07-06 12:00:00 UTC" "2020-07-06 23:00:00 UTC"
#[4] "2020-07-06 02:00:00 UTC"
```

You can then use `format` to keep part that you are interested in.

```
format(floor_date(as.POSIXct(df$time, 'UTC', format = '%H:%M'), 'hour'), '%H:%M')
#[1] "18:00" "12:00" "23:00" "02:00"
```

---

A solution without date-time manipulation using regex :

```
sub(':.*', ':00', df$time)
#[1] "18:00" "12:00" "23:00" "2:00"
```

However, note that manipulating date and times using regex is probably not the best option.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(time = c("18:40", "12:20", "23:59", "2:15")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Sorry just one last thing. For the second code chunk, how do I turn those strings into "time"?

Comment: If by `time` you mean `POSIXct`, as I mentioned you need to have both date and time in it. You can't only have hours and minutes in it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `Period` class in `lubridate` is what you need:

```
library(lubridate)
```

1. Parse periods with hour and minute

   ```
   hm(df$time)
   # [1] "18H 40M 0S" "12H 20M 0S" "23H 59M 0S" "2H 15M 0S"
   ```
2. Extract hours component

   ```
   hour(hm(df$time))
   # [1] 18 12 23  2
   ```
3. Create a new period object

   ```
   hours(hour(hm(df$time)))
   # [1] "18H 0M 0S" "12H 0M 0S" "23H 0M 0S" "2H 0M 0S"
   ```